# hierarchy defined in core.clj file vs. hierarchy defined in REPL

Tags: clojure

i am executing the code from the 'Practical Clojure' book and there is something that i do not understand about hierarchies. Maybe somebody can give me a hint about my problem. Thanks in advance!

By adding the following code in one Leiningen project :

```
 (derive ::human ::good)
 (derive ::elf ::good)
```

In one REPL session I am executing (use :reload 'test.core) and it returns nil ~ so it is loaded.

```
(isa? ::human ::good) ; => false????
```

If I type in the REPL the two above forms and by querying the hierarchy with the same syntax

```
(isa? ::human ::good) ; => true.
```

What syntax should i use for the version loaded from the test.core.clj file? 
I have tested and it is correct by adding to the core.clj another form

```
(def x (isa? ::human ::good) ; x is true.
```

regards,
DG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that keywords beginning with two colons are read as namespaced keywords where the namespace is the current namespace unless you explicitly specify a namespace alias before the dash.

In `test.core` `::human` is read as `:test.core/human`. In the REPL you are most likely in the `user` namespace, so it is read as `:user/human` - a different keyword!

You can switch into the `test.core` namespace via `(in-ns 'test.core)`.

Or you can fully qualify the keyword:

`(isa? :test.core/human :test.core/good)`

Or you can use an alias to `test.core`:

```
(require '[test.core :as test])
(isa? ::test/human ::test/good) ;; notice two colons: alias will be resolved
```

Or you can not use namespaced keywords.

```
(derive :human :elf)
```

This would be unidiomatic as using `derive` without a hierachy as first argument will change the global hierachy (where we don't want to mess with other names). Instead, you could have your own hierachy which you control entirely on your own:

```
(def h (make-hierachy))
(derive h :human :elf)
(isa? h :human :elf)
```

As you can see the beautiful Clojure provides many ways to suit or needs.